# How to secure a proxy authorization?

Tags: proxy, authorization

I have a private proxy running on a cloud server.

I have some users which I would like to allow access.

The typical way of requesting authorization is for the server to return a HTTP 407 response, with a proxy-authenticate header.  The client then responds with a proxy-authorization header.

However, everyone in the world can see this proxy-authorization header.

As far as I understand, this could have been resolved if I could just connect to the proxy via HTTPS, but this is non-standard and not supported by many browsers.

I want only my users to be able to access the proxy.  What is the correct way to achieve this security?

Note: I would strongly prefer not to have to whitelist IP addresses per user, as this requires ongoing maintenance of the whitelisted IP list.

Answer (score 2):

> ... I could just connect to the proxy via HTTPS, but this is non-standard and not supported by many browsers

It is supported by Google Chrome and similar and by Firefox. But it can often not be directly configured using the systems proxy settings. See for example [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/secure-web-proxy/) how to configure it using the command line or a PAC file.

If this is not an option, then this leaves only normal HTTP proxy or SOCKS supported by all major browsers. None of these provides any security by its own though, this means what you want is not possible using the browser alone.  One would instead need to create a protected tunnel to your proxy which the browser then can use. This could be done for example using a VPN between the client system and your server, or with application specific tunnel using [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/) or similar.